# How to identify what permissions are needed to access a server share

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions

Using Windows Exploer, I enter the following UNC path in the address line and hit ENTER: 
\TestServer

I see a share folder, MyShareFolder. I right mouse click on the folder name and clicl "properties" and go to the "Security" tab. I see in the "GHroup or User Names" list box teh following list:

```
L_MYDEPT_SharedFolder_C
L_TestServer_SharedFolder_C
Administrators (MyServer\Administrators)
```

The names that are prefixed by L I assume are local groups that are defined on the service. I presume access is controlled by adding Global Group names to these local groups.

Given that I am not the Admin of this box, is there any possible way that I can identify what gllobal group I need to request access to to get access to this share?

How do companies normally do this? it creates kaos in when users know what they need to get access to but don't know what to request.

Comment: Just ask for access to the Shares. Your admins will know what groups to add you to.

Comment: I agree with @joeqwerty this is going to be entirely an organization question and how they handle access. Without looking at AD we could at best guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network admins for your organization should know what group they need to add you in. By the sound of it, `L_MYDEPT_SharedFolder_C` would most likely be the group that you need to be added into but you can be added to any of those groups to get access (I doubt they would add you to the Administrators group though). Once added to the group, you should be able to easily view the `MyShareFolder`.

Comment: There are three types of Windows permissions in general. `List Folder Contents` `Permits viewing and accessing of the file's contents as well as executing of the file`, `Read` `Permits viewing and listing of files and subfolders`, and `Write` access `Permits adding of files and subfolders`.  Most people don't realize you might see the file but have no permission to actually open the file and view the contents of the file.

Comment: We should assume that the network administrators would know that. He is only asking which group he needs to be added under.

Comment: I was informing the author, providing clarification, into the reason the Administrator should be contacted.